# Anaconda installation problems - how to uninstall Anaconda (Windows)

Tags: python, windows, anaconda, uninstallation

I recently tried installing Anaconda for my Windows 10 laptop. Unfortunately, this didn't seem to work, as there seems to be no actual Anaconda application on my computer, rather just a collection of folders and files on my desktop. I think this problem can be attributed to me downloading the 32-bit version of Anaconda while my OS is 64-bit, though I am not sure this was the problem. Regardless, I would now like to uninstall Anaconda from my computer. **How would I go about uninstalling Anaconda from Windows despite Anaconda not fully downloading and only consisting of various folders on my desktop.** I'm not super computer-savvy so typing in commands directly into the console seems a bit intimidating.

Answer (score 1):

Because the program isn't actually installed, you can honestly just throw all of the files needed TO install Anaconda into your trash or recycle bin. If you go to "Programs and Features" and you don't see Anaconda, then those other files and folders can just be thrown away.

Comment: Be aware that Anaconda is titled something like "Python 3.6.0 (Anaconda 4.3.1 64 bit)" in the Programs and Features list. It is not titled "Anaconda."

Comment: Tahnk you so much for your help. Anaconda (listed as "Python 3.6.0 (Anaconda 4.3.1 64 bit)" ) actually is in my programs and features list, but I am unable to access the Anaconda Navigator, as their seems to be no icon on my desktop and I am unable to search for it through "Start". Could this be because I have the 32-bit version of Anaconda downloaded and I have a 64-bit OS (I thought I should do this because Python on my computer was 64-bit) or because I downloaded Anaconda under "users" instead of Desktop. I also downloaded Anaconda twice, if that could be causing some of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There also is a

> Uninstall-Anaconda.exe

directly in your Anaconda folder. But I'm not sure if it does something more than just deleting the folder/files.